# PrimeFaces overlayPanel outside its container

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to display an OverlayPanel into a Carousel, but this panel is wider than the Carousel, so its contents are not completely shown.

I've tried adding a `z-index` style value to the panel, but it still stays "inside" the Carousel.

Is there any way to show it completely, by drawing its overflow outside the Carousel?

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation from primefaces [OverLayPanel Documentation www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/overlayPanel.html](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/overlayPanel.html) you should use

```
appendToBody="true"
```

The overlay panel with it should do the trick.

Comment: This fixed my problem but had the side effect of appending the panel at the bottom of my element (a p:dataTabel). I resolved it using: for="(id of the table cell element)"